# Can I set a specific memory alignment with dma_alloc_coherent?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, memory-alignment, dma

I need to allocate several large DMA buffers (8 MiB and larger) with 8 KiB (8192) alignment. To allocate a large buffer I use `dma_alloc_coherent` and kernel's command-line parameter `cma`. But how I can set 8 KiB alignment for my buffer?

Comment: While waiting for a better answer you could potentially allocate 8MiB+8KiB and pick the lowest aligned address.

Comment: @thatotherguy, 4KiB is enough b/c alignment is guaranteed to be page size.